# Using python helper_funcs.funcs

Tags: python

I was trying to get someone else's code to run in python

I have:

```
import helper_funcs.funcs as f
```

and

```
queue = f.get_res().iloc[:, 0].tolist()
```

I keep getting error:

> No module named 'helper_funcs.funcs'

I installed helper_funcs, but I am not seeing any reference to helper_funcs.funcs

I tried installing helper_funcs.funcs but was not successful

Thanks

Comment: How exactly did you install helper_funcs?

Comment: Are you sure `funcs` is a module, and not a class? You probably want `from helper_funcs import funcs as f`.

Comment: In spyder, I issued command !pip install helper_funcs

Comment: the "import helper_funcs.funcs as f" was taken from his code so I assume it works